Projection into eigenspace decompositions.
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map with minimal polynomial $$p(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{e_1}...(x-\lambda_n)^{e_n}$$over $k$ where $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in k$. It is well-known that we have decomposition $$V =\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Ker}\left(T-\lambda_i\operatorname{Id}_V\right)^{e_i}$$ as internal direct sum. Let $V_i=\operatorname{Ker}\left(T-\lambda_i\operatorname{Id}_V\right)^{e_i}$ and let $\pi_i:V\to V_i$ be the projection. I am asked to find a polynomial $p_i\in k[x]$ such that $$\pi_i=p_i(T).$$
I begin by writing out $$\left(T-\lambda_i\operatorname{Id}_V\right)^{e_i}\circ \pi_i=0.$$Upon writing out in the action of polynomial, $$(x-\lambda_i)^{e_i}\cdot \pi_i=0.$$ If $\lambda_i$ is not $0$ I think I can take out the constant but the remaining terms would still be acting on $\pi_i$. I think this problem should not look difficult. Any hints?

Hmmm. Projections have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$. By the spectral mapping theorem, $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace = p_i(\sigma(T))$. If these thoughts are correct, this might limit your choice a little.

The co-domain of $\pi_i$ does not make sense.  Also the statement $(x-\lambda_i)^{e_i}\cdot \pi_i=0.$ does not make sense.
